# How to set some default or start core data entity values?

Tags: ios, swift, nsmanagedobject, viewdidload

I am trying to save some default or start data for an core data entity. My app scans a code and stores corresponding data into core data (entity is ScannedVisitor), this part works. But I like to have a default entry.

I have :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // scanner code
    self.cameraLayerWithBorder()

    // Default Entry
    let defaultItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("ScannedVisitor", inManagedObjectContext: moContext) as! ScannedVisitor
    defaultItem.sLastName = "Test"
    defaultItem.sCompany = "Test"
    defaultItem.sPhone = "0123456789"
    defaultItem.sEmail = "info@test.com"
    defaultItem.sJobTitle = "Job name"
    defaultItem.sCity = "New York"

    // end test Default Entry
}
```

But this crashes my app.

or should i add the code to ScannedVisitor.swift somehow?

[**EDIT**]

Here is a screenshot of the error message I get:

[image]

[**EDIT 2**]

I deleted my already scanned codes and data and now my app immediately crashes and spits out the message "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
I replaced ! for ?

```
  let defaultItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("ScannedVisitor", inManagedObjectContext: moContext) as? ScannedVisitor
        defaultItem!.sLastName = "Test"
        defaultItem!.sCompany = "Test"
        defaultItem!.sPhone = "0123456789"
        defaultItem!.sEmail = "info@test.nl"
        defaultItem!.sJobTitle = "Job name"
        defaultItem!.sCity = "New York"
```

Browsing around I see people renaming the entity class, like so

```
ScannedVisitor
```

to

```
MyProject.ScannedVisitor
```

in the Data Model Inspector. But when I try this XCode 7 removes the period and rewrites it immediately to

```
MyProjectScannedVisitor
```

[**EDIT 3**]

How can I make sure the default entry is just added once and not everytime onload?

I thought by checking the property but I get an error:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
...    
let tmpCheckEntry: ABRecordRef = ABRecordCopyValue("Test", kABPersonLastNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as? String
```

but that results in a EXC_BAD_ACCESS .......??

Comment: what is the crash description?

Comment: @the_UB I get unexpectedly found nil while unwrappigin an Optional value when I scroll (I did scan some data already)

Comment: try `?` instead of `!`. and check this too:[found nil while unwrapping an Optional value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307688/ios-8-core-data-stack-fatal-error-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: I replaced with ` as? ScannedVisitor ` but still it crashes my app (see EDIT 2). I think somehow the app doesn't see the default entry.

Comment: Can you find out exactly which line is causing error?

Comment: Got it! Stupid me I did not provide a default value for every attribute. I forgot one attribute. I have set it to "test"  and now I seem to have a workable app

Comment: lol! Got me wandering

Comment: @the_UB one last question about this one. How can I make sure the default entry is just added once in core data?